# Hashtable new entries permanent loop and finding key with lowest value

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

```
string v;
int k;
Console.WriteLine("enterv");
v = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("enter k");
k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

ht.Add(v, k);
```

This is my code and I have it in function but it never ends, why is that??

And also, I'm trying to find the lowest key in hash table, and my professor gave this example but I can't get it work.

```
Hashtable tabela=new Hashtable();
string ime;   
int min=100000;
foreach(string k in tabela) {
    if(tabela[k]<min){
        min=tabela[k];
        ime=k;   
    }
}
```

How can I compare the keys properly?

Comment: First, if you have two different questions, please post them separately. Second, what do you mean by saying that the first code example "never ends"? There aren't any loops, so the only way I see for it to get stuck is if you aren't entering any response to the prompts (you'll have to enter any text for the first entry, and an integer for the second). Third, in general please be specific about "can't get it to work". Here, we can easily see you're enumerating an empty collection, so of course you don't find anything. But other issues may not be so easy if you aren't specific.

Comment: @PeterDuniho sorry about that, should I do that now? Also, for my first problem, the code never ends, in a way that when I add one element, it goes back to the first line again, and never ends. Not sure why either because it's NOT in a loop. As for the second problem, my professor gave me the solution as I posted it, but I have a problem in the line if(tabela[k]<min) saying I can't compare 2 variables of that type.

Comment: The `Hashtable` class is obsolete. You should use the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class instead.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've read about the differences of hashtable and dictionary, but the task I'm doing requires to be done with hashtable specifically.

Comment: Is this for school? That's the only valid reason to use a Hashtable. `Hasntable` has been _replaced_ by `Dictionary`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, it is for school.

Comment: Tell your instructor that `Hashtable` was replaced by `Dictionary` back in .NET 2.0 - over eight years ago. There's no excuse for teaching old stuff to new students.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Hm.. that would be a little harsh of me, I don't want to argue with him, I just want to learn what am I doing wrong :)

Comment: It's not harsh of _you_, it's harsh of _me_. Please feel free to quote me. Unless your instructor thinks his students will be using .NET 1.1, there is simply no excuse for it. At all. School is meant to prepare you for the real world. Most of the real world pretty much stopped using `Hashtable` for new development eight years ago.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the suggestion but I think I'll pass on that.. if you can help me with the problem I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @user912839123: at this point, since someone has explained how to use the non-generic `Hashtable` class, IMHO you should delete the "loop mystery" part of the question from this one and present it as a separate question. When you do, provide a better code example, one that is complete but reproduces the issue _with the minimum amount of code possible_. It is not possible that your code loops without _something_ causing it to loop. And you didn't post any code that would cause it to loop. So obviously you've left _something_ out of your posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var minValue = Int32.MaxValue;
string minKey = null;
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in ht)
{
    if ((int) item.Value < minValue)
    {
        minValue = (int) item.Value;
        minKey = (string) item.Key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the task specifies that it must use hashtables unfortunately.

Comment: that's nice solution. What exactly is Int32.MaxValue? The maximum value of 32 bit system? And also, what about the first problem of mine? Can you help me about it? It keeps looping forever, and I don't have it in loop anywhere.

Comment: `int.MaxValue` is the largest value that can be represented in the type. It's 32 bits and it uses two's-complement signed representation, so `int.MaxValue` is (2^31)-1. For an algorithm like this, it's the appropriate starting value for your `minKey` variable, because you know there won't be any values larger than that. There's one little gap here, which is the case where the smallest value in the collection is in fact `int.MaxValue`. This this implementation will overlook it. That can be fixed by checking `minKey` first and always assigning the minimum value if it's still null.